# Android Emulator API 26 does not display adaptive icon

Tags: android

Android O introduced adaptive icons, so I went ahead and tried to implement it. Using AS 3.0, I've followed the steps and created the `mipmap-anydpi-v26` directory, and within it a `ic_launcher.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <background android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_background"/>
    <foreground android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_foreground"/>
</adaptive-icon>
```

I'm running a  Pixel emulator running Android O, but for some reason it's simply showing what appears to be the default icon (green background with android logo on top).

If I change the icon back to my legacy icon, it works flawlessly.

Am I missing some here, or is this some kind of emulator issue?

Comment: I'm having this issue now, did you ever get this figured out?

Comment: Figured it out, I needed build tools 26.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive.html) `ic_launcher.xml` should be placed in `res/mipmap-anydpi` without specifying `-v26` at the end. Also check the icon size and a simpler icon e.g. with background as a color (`<background android:drawable="@color/ic_background"/>`)

Have you tried that?

Comment: `mipmap-anydpi-v26` is auto generated in AS 3.0 to prevent conflict for the previous versions. I did also check the icon sizes and even used the built in image asset tool to create icons to ensure I wasn't making any dimension mistakes, but the AS generated ones did not work also unfortunately

Comment: then it sounds like it is an issue of the emulator, have you tried another one?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. Switching to `buildTools` 26 solved it for me.

Edit: I see [casolorz has already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46058595/android-emulator-api-26-does-not-display-adaptive-icon/46545962#comment79090917_46058595) the same thing

Comment: Switching to `buildTools` 26.0.2 did not work for me. For reference I'm running: `compileSdkVersion = 26
    targetSdkVersion = 26
    minSdkVersion = 16
    buildToolsVersion = "26.0.2"`

Comment: Derek, you should be having some other issue. The problem with me and obviously @casolorz was that we were building with a version of buildTools that did not understand what we were saying. So we switched to 26 (we were at a previous version) so it understands the new things from Android O. Also take a look at fmaccaroni's answer above: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46058906/2528232 and make sure to follow the official docs.